# Mysql querying with id and last_name yields 0 results

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySql When I search with id and last name I see no results. Below

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE id = '-2105192515' AND last_name='JOHNSON' 
0 Results ----- (id = mzb_indiv_id)
```

[image]

But when searching with only Id I get one record match. Below is the query

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE id = '-2105192515' 
1 Record match .  --- (id = mzb_indiv_id)
```

[image]

Also when searching with last_name I see the results too. But why is there a difference between the above two searches?

Comment: What are the results for both those queries?

Comment: You may benefit from posting the row where both of these conditions are met. As it stands, the logical assumption is that you don't have a row where the id is -2105192515 AND the last_name is 'JOHNSON'

Comment: Scath, I added the results.

Comment: Kai, Sure I will add the rows.

Comment: Kai , I added the images too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See my updated answer, there is a space in the name in the table.

Comment: Yes. I saw that. Thanks a lot MatBailie. But how to ignore those spaces while matching with the db value

Comment: Try using LIKE, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query only returns a row if it has that `id` ***and*** also has that `last_name`, in the same row.

*(It does **not** mean : rows with this id and also rows with that last name.)*

I guess the result from your second query doesn't have the `last_name` JOHNSON?

Perhaps you want an OR rather than an AND?

***Edit***

Your example data has `' JOHNSON'` rather than `'JOHNSON'` (an extra space at the start)

Try `last_name LIKE '%JOHNSON%'` or `TRIM(last_name) = 'JOHNSON'`

Comment: Thanks MatBailie. Your suggestion helped.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, **first thing** I found

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
    WHERE id = '-2105192515'
    AND   last_name='JOHNSON'
```

Here column name is '**`last_name`**' but in in info below you wrote column name '**`last_Name`**'.

Check your column names, as the missing column would give error in executing, so it is highly unlikely.

**Second thing**: are you spelling '***JOHNSON***' the same way it is stored in your database? no spaces included?.

Please, post the result set with both queries to get a proper, and more valid answer.

Comment: These are comments rather than answers, and mysql is not case sensitive by default for column names

Comment: Hyder, I added the images of the results. Please advise

Comment: Hyder. You are correct. The vale for last_name column in  the db has the value with trailing spaces. How can i remove these trailing spaces in the db value when searching?

Comment: since, i am late to the party, and Mat bailie, has updated his answer after you found out that spaces were issue. and @MatBailie I at least picked the right guess. :) about spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The row which `id` is `-2105192515` has a `last_name` column value which is **not** equal to `JOHNSON`

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE id = '-2105192515' AND last_name='JOHNSON'
```

This query means - return all the rows that their  `id = '-2105192515'` **AND**  the `last_name='JOHNSON'`

You may have wanted to use `OR` instead?